# swt scollbar and slider

Tags: swt

Would anybody have an examples of a scrollbar 
in swt within a composite as I am having alot
of trouble trying to get a scrollbar to work
within my composite?
Also I have a slider in which I have used a 
switch statement to display different messages 
at different positions in the slider but it works
for example 20 displays 'Hi there your at 20' and
when I move it to 30 it displays a different message
but when I move back to 20 from 30 it wont
display positions 20 message?
Anybody with any suggestions?
Thanks,
Ann.

Comment: Can you provide some code to see exactly what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question, have a look at `org.eclipse.swt.custom.ScrolledComposite`...

There are quite a few [SWT Snippets](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/) for [ScrolledComposite](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/#scrolledcomposite). Always look here before asking for examples.